# XPath expression won't accept variable

Tags: powershell, xpath

Here is the sample code:

```
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.load('C:\Users\Example\Desktop\examp.xml')

# this works
$node = $xml.selectSingleNode("//SERVER[@name='EXAMPLE']")

# this does not work
$t = 'EXAMPLE'
$node = $xml.selectSingleNode("//SERVER[@name=$t]")
```

Why? If you would like to see the XML as well, please say so.

Comment: The last example evaluates to the literal string `//SERVER[@name=EXAMPLE]`, without the quotes. Try `$t = "'EXAMPLE'"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in XPath expressions must be enclosed in quotes (either single or double). As @MathiasR.Jessen pointed out in his comment to your question, your expression evaluates to `//SERVER[@name=EXAMPLE]` when it should be `//SERVER[@name="EXAMPLE"]` or `//SERVER[@name='EXAMPLE']`. The quotes in the expression

```
$t = 'EXAMPLE'
```

are simply for defining `EXAMPLE` as a string *for PowerShell*. They don't become part of the string and are thus not present when expanding the variable in the string with the XPath expression.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $t = 'EXAMPLE'
PS C:\> $t
EXAMPLE
PS C:\> "//SERVER[@name=$t]"      # wrong
//SERVER[@name=EXAMPLE]
PS C:\> "//SERVER[@name='$t']"    # correct
//SERVER[@name='EXAMPLE']
PS C:\> "//SERVER[@name=`"$t`"]"  # correct
//SERVER[@name="EXAMPLE"]
```

Add the missing quotes to your XPath expression and the problem will disappear:

```
$node = $xml.selectSingleNode("//SERVER[@name='$t']")
```