# `Splinter`'s `is_text_present` method won't accept the variables that I am loading from a JSON file

Tags: python, web-scraping, browser, selenium-chromedriver, splinter

## TL;DR:

**The Goal** - My goal with V2 is to get a `for` loop to execute the exact way a handful of `if`/`elif` statements do in my V1, but across multiple users that are stored in a JSON file.

**The Problem (*Presumably*)** - `Splinter`'s `is_text_present` method doesn't want to accept the variables that I am loading from a JSON file.

**Solutions Attempted: Outcome** - [Angleton's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387587/xpath-expression-wont-accept-variable): Didn't achieve the goal

## Full Post:

I am trying to simplify a Python script by turning `if`/`elif` statements into a `for` loop.

The script's current version, V1, executes as expected and the code looks something like this:

### V1 Final: Answers the Security Questions

```
if browser.is_text_present('Example_Question_1'):

    browser.find_by_id('secretquestion0').first.fill('Example_Answer_1')



elif browser.is_text_present('Example_Question_2'):

    browser.find_by_id('secretquestion0').first.fill('Example_Answer_2')



elif browser.is_text_present('Example_Question_3'):

    browser.find_by_id('secretquestion0').first.fill('Example_Answer_3')



elif browser.is_text_present('Example_Question_4'):

    browser.find_by_id('secretquestion0').first.fill('Example_Answer_4')



elif browser.is_text_present('Example_Question_5'):

    browser.find_by_id('secretquestion0').first.fill('Example_Answer_5')
```

The script's second version, V2, pulls from a JSON file... the data in the JSON is organized like this:

### V2: JSON File

```
{

    "User": {

        "username": "username",

        "password": "password",

        "Security_Questions": [

           {

                "question": "'Example_Question_1'",

                "answer": "'Example_Answer_1'"

            },

            {

                "question": "'Example_Question_2'",

                "answer": "'Example_Answer_2'"

            },

            {

                "question": "'Example_Question_3'",

                "answer": "'Example_Answer_3'"

            },

            {

                "question": "'Example_Question_4'",

                "answer": "'Example_Answer_4'"

            },

            {

                "question": "'Example_Question_5'",

                "answer": "'Example_Answer_5'"

            }

            ]

    }

}
```

As I am building my V2, I believe **I am running into a problem with `Splinter`'s `is_text_present` method: It doesn't want to accept the `question` or `answer` variables that I am loading from the JSON File**. I am not running into any errors... the script simply finishes with exit code 0.

I edited my JSON data to reflect the solution presented in [Angleton's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387587/xpath-expression-wont-accept-variable), but had no luck with it.

Here is my first stab at the `for` loop that will replace the `if`/`elif` statements for the script's second version:

### V2 Draft: Answers the Security Questions

```
for user in user_data:

.

.

.   

    for security_info in user_data[user]["Security_Questions"]:

        question = security_info["question"]

        answer = security_info["answer"] 

        if browser.is_text_present(question):

            browser.find_by_id('secretquestion0').first.fill(answer)
```

**My goal with V2 is to get this `for` loop to execute the exact way the V1 does, but across multiple users that I'll store in the JSON File.**

Been at this for a while now and I am not sure what else I should try...

Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON, the questions contain an apostrophe (') at the end and start, so the browser tries to search for `'Example_Question_1'`, `'Example_Question_2'` when the question, according to the V1, is `Example_Question_1`. You simply need to remove the apostrophes from the JSON file.